Форматирование блока кода { ..... } который ни к чему не относиться в Clion
Какая настройка в Clion отвечает за форматирования блока кода, который ни к чему не относиться. Например у меня есть код:
while (true) 
{
    ........
    std::string current_link; 
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> queue_lock(queue_mutex);
        if (links_queue.empty()) { return; }
    }
    .......
}

и при форматировании он превращается в:
while (true) {
    ........
    std::string current_link; {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> queue_lock(queue_mutex);
        if (links_queue.empty()) { return; }
    }
    .......
}

Как сделать, чтобы фигурная скобочка которая ни к чему не относиться не переносилась на предыдущую строку?

Тогда уж все остальные тоже стоит на отдельной строке оставлять, то бишь перейти на стиль Алмана.
